# Choose the data from 3 tables has has same data in one column and different data in another column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
tb_a                tb_b             tb_c
==============      ==============   ==============
|id|doc1|urla|      |id|doc2|urlb|   |id|doc3| sum|
==============      ==============   ==============
| 1| c1 |url1|      | 1| c2 |urla|   | 1| c2 |sum1|
| 2| c3 |url3|      | 2| c4 |urlb|   | 2| c3 |sum3|
| 3| c2 |url2|      | 3| c6 |urlc|   | 3| c4 |sum4|
==============      ==============   | 4| c6 |sum6|
                                     ==============
```

First, I wanna check `tb_a` and `tb_b`. If there're same data in `doc1` and `doc2`, I just use data `doc1` in `tb_a`. here's first query :

```
SELECT 
   a.doc1
FROM 
   tb_a a
LEFT JOIN 
   tb_b b
   ON a.doc1 = b.doc2
WHERE 
   b.doc2 IS NULL
```

then left join with `tb_c` to get `sum`. can I make those processes in one query? how? thank you :)

from the example, so the result must be :

```
c3 url3 sum3 
c2 url2 sum1
c4 urlb sum4
c6 urlc sum6
```

Comment: are the tables related to each other by `id`?or they have no relationship at all?

Comment: @JohnWoo no, they're auto_increment ... the datas come from different resources

Comment: why `c2`? isn't it `c1`? because the result for `tb_a` and `tb_a` is `c1` and `c3`.

Comment: @JohnWoo `tb_a` has `c2` , `tb_b` also has `c2`. I avoid duplication,  so I just take data from `tb_a` only.

Comment: you can now check my answer since you have updated your question. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join all the tables using `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT  a.doc3 DOCValue, 
        COALESCE(b.urla, c.urlb) AS URLValue,
        a.`SUm` AS SUMValue
FROM    tb_c a
        LEFT JOIN tb_a b
            ON a.doc3 = b.doc1
        LEFT JOIN tb_b c
            ON a.doc3 = c.doc2
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a5a3/1)

Comment: great ! I don't know about COALESCE before. thank you so much, sir ! :)

Comment: basically, `COALESCE` returns the first `non-null` value provided on the list.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return all records which match on doc in A, B & C.  Which I think is what you're after.

```
SELECT 
   a.doc1, C.SUM
FROM 
   tb_a a
LEFT JOIN 
   tb_b b
   ON a.doc1 = b.doc2
left join TB_C C ON C.DOC3=B.DOC2
WHERE 
   b.doc2 IS NOT NULL
```